# Executar o próximo som em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma pasta de áudios com vozes/palavras gravadas em wave e quero executar o Javascript em casos diferentes. Por exemplo: "Erro ao logar. Por favor, tente novamente". Encontrei alguns códigos pela web mas eles não executam os áudios um por um. Aqui no Stack encontrei este código -postado pelo usuário the flash- que aparentemente se aproxima mais do que eu necessito:

```
function loadPlayer() {
    var audioPlayer = new Audio();
    audioPlayer.controls="controls";
    audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended',nextSong,false);
    audioPlayer.addEventListener('error',errorFallback,true);
    document.getElementById("player").appendChild(audioPlayer);
    nextSong();
}
function nextSong() {
    if(urls[next]!=undefined) {
        var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
        if(audioPlayer!=undefined) {
            audioPlayer.src=urls[next];
            audioPlayer.load();
            audioPlayer.play();
            next++;
        } else {
            loadPlayer();
        }
    } else {
        alert('the end!');
    }
}
function errorFallback() {
        nextSong();
}
function playPause() {
    var audioPlayer = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
    if(audioPlayer!=undefined) {
        if (audioPlayer.paused) {
            audioPlayer.play();
        } else {
            audioPlayer.pause();
        }
    } else {
        loadPlayer();
    }
}
function pickSong(num) {
    next = num;
    nextSong();
}

var urls = new Array();
    urls[0] = 'audio.mp3';
    urls[1] = 'audio.mp3';
    urls[2] = 'audio.mp3';
    urls[3] = 'audio.mp3';
    urls[4] = 'audio.mp3';
    urls[5] = 'audio.mp3';   
    urls[6] = 'audio.mp3';       
var next = 0;
```

Quero deixar claro que, estou fazendo isso só por aprendizado. Me formei recentemente em Técnico de informática para internet e estou amando a área de programação.  :)

Comment: O que que este código faz e porquê não atende? Qual o erro que dá ou função que tem dúvida? Por favor, em vez de responder nos comentários, clique em [edit] e acrescente detalhes na pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PlaneX,

Tem alguns projetos que podem te ajudar a fazer um player muito bom utilizando apenas Javascript e angular;

- http://danielstern.github.io/ngAudio/#/audio/audio%7Csong1.mp3 - Te permite criar playlist pegar todos os parametros da música e inserir sons para eventos como mousehover click entre outros.
- http://colthreepv.github.io/angular-media-player/ - Um projeto maduro que permite fazer players robustos utilizando angular.

Mas para o seu problema imediato use HTML5 vou mostrar. Vou usar Jquery para facilicar

```
//Coloque um audio no seu corpinho de HTML
$('<audio id="chatAudio">
    <source src="ERROU.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="ERROU.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>').appendTo('body');
```

Em seguida damos play em um seletor do evento:

```
//Errou a senha produção
$('#alerta').show{
$('#chatAudio')[0].play();
}
```

Ou fazer em Javascript direto :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Audio</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
                 }
   </script>

<input type="button" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src="http://dev.interactive-creation-works.net/1/1.ogg" ></audio>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Consegui executar através dos arquivos de áudio que eu contenho (VOX Half-Life). Cada áudio, agora, está sendo executado em diferentes eventos. Por exemplo: wrong.mp3 e password.mp3.

Valeu, Dom.